# Sweetalert confirm button breaks input fields

Tags: sweetalert

I have a strange bug when I use an input field on a sweet alert I can't have the cursor inside my input field here is a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gvzwu5st/

If I include

```
showConfirmButton: false
```

Then it works fine here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/16L4sddt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have `showConfirmButton: true`, the `openModal()` function (line 653) gives focus to the confirm button (line 662):

```
$okButton.focus();
```

When you try to click in the input field, the `handleOnBlur()` function (line 396) is called because the confirm button loses the focus. The functions defines the `$targetElement` variable which refers to the confirm button (line 397). Skipping some lines... the function will loop through each button of the modal to check if it is the element that got the focus. In your case, the target element is the input field, so it is not any of the buttons. The variable `btnIndex` keeps the value `-1`. Lines 413-416:

```
if (btnIndex === -1) {
  // Something in the dom, but not a visible button. Focus back on the button.
  $targetElement.focus();
}
```

So the confirm button (`$targetElement`) is given back the focus, which prevents the input field from ever receiving it.